# Long audio files to text real quick in Python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I want to have audio files converted in text. For this purpose I am using **speechrecognition** library and then use **google cloud speech to text AP**I to convert it. I tried doing so by splitting audio in chunks. However, it takes much time than expected. For longer audio files **example of 60 minutes, I want to achieve results in maximum 5 minute**. Is there any way to do so. Please help me out.
Here is my code :

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file("testaudio.wav" , "wav") 
chunk_length_ms = 4000 # pydub calculates in millisec
chunks = make_chunks(myaudio, chunk_length_ms) #Make chunks of one sec

#Export all of the individual chunks as wav files

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk_name = "chunk{0}.wav".format(i)
    print ("exporting", chunk_name)
    chunk.export(chunk_name, format="wav")

i=0
for chunk in chunks:
    print ("in chunks")
    chunk_silent = AudioSegment.silent(duration = 10)
    audio_chunk = chunk_silent + chunk + chunk_silent
    audio_chunk.export("./chunk{0}.wav".format(i), bitrate ='192k', format ="wav")
    filename = 'chunk'+str(i)+'.wav'
    print("Processing chunk "+str(i))
    file = filename
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioFile(file) as source:
        #r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio_listened = r.listen(source)
    try:
        rec = r.recognize_google_cloud(audio_listened)
        print (rec)
    except:
        rec = r.recognize_google_cloud(audio_listened,show_all=True)
        print(rec,type(rec))

    i += 1
```

Comment: I created as many threads as chunks and started processing them at the same time. Anyone has better solution, yet?